# What's the name of the song that's played when you die in Pitfall?

Tags: game-music-identification, pitfall

What's the name of the song that's played when you die in Pitfall?  My understanding is that the song itself (not specifically Pitfall's recording of it) is an old thing that nobody holds any claim over, and I'm trying to search for a free copy to embed into some software.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 5 note 'death fanfare' from Pitfall is an adaptation of the [opening notes of the theme song to the old TV and radio show Dragnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragnet_(theme_music)):

It should be noted that, as the original date of publication was in 1953, the theme should not be presumed to be in the public domain.